# Can I use 1 GSM antenna connected to multiple GSM modems?

Tags: mobile

I have multiple GSM modems connected to a laptop and now I want to increase their signal. I thought in buying an antenna and a repeater and put the repeater next to the modems.

As far as I know, the repeater is commonly used to increase the signal in interiors, repeating the signal that receives from/to the antena on the roof. So if I put a receiver next to so the modems, supposedly, their will receive a better signal (the one that the repeater receives from the high gain antenna).

The question is: Will be they possible to send/receive high quantity of data at the same time using the same antenna?

Comment: It looks possible to me. You have 2 options here - use the repeater or if the modems support external antenna then you can use some kind of combiner to use all of them with only one external antenna without repeater.

Comment: We are going to test today the combined thingy. The repeater we bought to test this is broken or something because it won't worked with just 1 modem inside a "faraday box" and the external antenna outside it some meters away.

Comment: To update this, still not tried the combined thingy. Going to update when we test it.